# Как создать VIEW на основе таблицы не учитывая дубликатов записей?

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть таблица `ATEST` с данными:

```
create table ATEST (
    id number (9),
    data1 varchar2 (255))

insert into atest values (1, 100);
insert into atest values (1, 100);
insert into atest values (2, 200);
insert into atest values (2, 200);
insert into atest values (3, 300);
insert into atest values (3, 300);
```

Нужно создать на основе этой таблицы VIEW `V_ATEST` без дублирующих (идентичных) данных, то есть в которой будет всего три строки:

```
ID  DATA1
--  -----
1   100
2   200
3   300
```

Нашел достаточно много советов, как удалять дубликаты данных при помощи `DELETE` с использованием `rowid`, но мне он не подходит, так как данные в `ATEST` должны остаться, и данные нужно занести в новый `VIEW`.

Подскажите, как это сделать?

Comment: `CREATE VIEW v_atest AS SELECT DISTINCT * FROM atest;`. До синтаксиса Оракла подрихтуете самостоятельно...

Comment: Так пробовал. В данном случае Вью вывелся с одной строчкой "1 100", и на больших данных тоже работает некорректно.

Comment: Не верю. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f9ba5d13114e0c91792c3a09c20cde6c). Где-то косячите...

Comment: Накосячить в таком маленьком коде проблематично.. В sql developer на oracle, как я написал, создалась всего одна строчка, да и на больших данных не работает. Сейчас еще раз перепровел.

Comment: Тогда проверяйте корректность своей работы с SQL Developer - что-то упускаете. Ибо запрос детерминированный, синтаксис верный, а чудес не бывает. И в баги Оракла в подобных вещах я тоже не верю.

Comment: Сейчас еще раз перепроверил - да, Вы правы, я некорректно таблицу создал. Вариант правда работает, спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Представление исключающее дубликаты записей можно создать с [DISTINCT | UNIQUE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6) или клаузой [GROUP BY](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6).

Tак как на полную длину колонок или некоторые типы данных в листе выборки существуют ограничения, то лучше всегда указывать все колонки явно и отказаться от их неявного (`*`) привeдения.  Оба варианта представления ниже эквивалентны:

```
create or replace view atestv as
    select distinct id, data1 from atest
/
create or replace view atestv as
    select id, data1 from atest
    group by id, data1 
/
select * from atestv where id=1
/
        ID DATA1 
---------- ------
         1 100
```

В задаче с реальными данными ситуация, когда дублирующие записи ничем не отличаются, практически не встречается. Если нет колонки, по которой можно определить порядок дублирующих записей, то очень вероятно, что такая колонка скоро будет добавлена.

В этом случае следует сразу нумеровать записи оконной функцией:

```
create or replace view atestv as
    with t (id, data1, rn) as (
        select id, data1, row_number () over (partition by id, data1 order by null desc)  
        from atest t)
    select id, data1 from t where rn=1        
/
alter table atest add created timestamp default systimestamp
/
create or replace view atestv as
    with t (id, data1, rn) as (
        select id, data1, row_number () over (partition by id, data1 order by created desc)  
        from atest t)
    select id, data1 from t where rn=1        
/
select * from atestv where id=1
/
        ID DATA1 
---------- ------
         1 100
```